# Connect to remote server using 

Tags: php, hosting

I’m using Zen Cart (PHP) for my web site. I have images that is on my supplier’s remote server and my site is on Host Gator the only way to get the images show up on my site is to connect to their server using links to the images (per agreement). They tell me that ZenCart PHP does not allow you to serve images from a remote host. And I need to have a PHP programmer take a look at the code to see if he can manipulate the source code to allow this. Does anyone have solution for this? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

the other option is to sync images to a directory in your server from time to time (you can use rsync, wget etc.)

Answer (score 0):

From glancing through the documentation it appears that ZenCart looks to see if a file exists in order to decide whether or not the image has a picture.  PHP *can* do this over the internet, but it would mean that every time you opened a product webpage, there could be a dozen requests between your server and the supplier's server, just to see if image_MED and image_LRG and any other alternate images exist before your customer even gets to see the webpage, and then your customer would still have to connect to the supplier's server to get the image.

A programmer probably could alter ZenCart to remove all the alternate images, large images, image re-sizing and everything else that needs the actual image files to work, and allow it to use a URL hardcoded in the product database for the image.  If you want to have large or alternate images, you'd have to have the programmer add those to the database too.